# Rolling back a test (SQL Server 2008) with TestDriven.NET in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, rollback, testdriven.net

How do I cause all my tests to do a rollback on the SQL Server 2008 database from my Visual Studio 2010 test harness? I'm using TestDriven.NET to run the tests.